# Given a system of ODE'S, find value of $I$ when $S=\frac{\gamma}{r}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've got the following system of equations:
$$\begin{matrix}
    \dot{S}(t) && = && -rSI-\lambda S\\
    \dot{I}(t) && = &&rSI-\gamma I
    \end{matrix}$$
where all constants are greater than $0$. Therefore
$$\frac{dI}{dS}=\frac{rSI-\gamma I}{-rSI - \lambda S}$$
I want to find the value of $I$ when $S=\frac{\gamma}{r}$. I think I will have to solve the equation above to do this, but I don't really know how to do this. Can someone help me?

**Edit** This is an extract of a SIR model. The $I$ coordinate I am looking for is the maximum number of infected people.

Comment: This question doesn't really make any sense. $I$ can have any value when $S = \frac{\gamma}{r}$. You need something extra to constrain this problem.

Comment: As @AsAnExerciseProve said this question is not meaningful the way it is posed. Are you maybe looking for the equilibrium solution? Otherwise you need to specify initial conditions or a slope at the given point or something else.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{matrix}
    \dot{S}(t)  =  \frac{dS}{dt} && = &&  -rSI-\lambda S\\
    \dot{I}(t) =  \frac{dI}{dt} && = &&rSI-\gamma I
    \end{matrix}$$
You want to find the value of $I$ when $S=\frac{\gamma}{r}$

$$\frac{dI}{dt}  = rSI-\gamma I = r\frac{\gamma}{r}I-\gamma I=0$$
$$I=\text{constant}$$
This seems strange. Is there a typo in the question ?

Even more strange:  $\quad S=\frac{\gamma}{r}\quad\implies\quad \frac{dS}{dt}=0$

$$\frac{dS}{dt} = (-rI-\lambda) S=0$$
$$I=-\frac{\lambda}{r}$$

Of course $\begin{cases} I=-\frac{\lambda}{r}\\ S=\frac{\gamma}{r} \end{cases}$ is a particular and trivial solution. But without initial condition what is its signifiance ? There is a lack of context.

Comment: I wanto to find the value of the constant. I added an edit to my post, maybe that helps

Comment: I added an edit to my answer, maybe that helps.